# Jenkins sbt plugin config for build in subdirectory

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-plugins

I want to build a scala application via the jenkins sbt plugin.
The build.sbt file of my project does not reside in the root directory of the git repository, but in a subdirectory called 'webapp'.

How do i tell sbt within my Jenkins Job that it should do the building in that very subdirectory and not in the workspace root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the "Build using sbt" build step, then under the "Actions" field you will find an <kbd>Advanced…</kbd> button.

Clicking that will reveal a "Sub-directory Path" configuration option, where you can enter `webapp`.